# How can I unsecure a PDF that has no password?

Tags: pdf

How can I unsecure [this PDF](https://www.motivefinancial.com/SharedContent/documents/4312MF.pdf) (a transfer form) from [this Canadian bank](https://www.motivefinancial.com/AboutUs/WaysToBank/Transfers/)?

I've Adobe Acrobat DC Pro, Foxit PhantomPDF, and Nitro Pro. Here are my failed attempts:

1. https://www.sodapdf.com/unlock-pdf/: The website didn't do anything, and only alleged:

> The uploaded file is not secured and does not have any restrictions that can be removed.

2. I [opened the PDF in Chrome](https://www.tipard.com/resource/how-to-unsecure-a-pdf.html), but obtained this PDF with an error message:

[image]

3. https://smallpdf.com spawned the same PDF with the same error message overhead in 2.
4. https://pdf.io/unlock/, ilovepdf.com deceivingly spawned a PDF as if it worked, but it didn't. The resultant PDF can't be edited; I can't add text or pictures.

Comment: @Dave This is a simple common form; I don't think the bank would care (or know?) if my grandparents unsecured it?

Comment: I had to protect this question due to the answers it was attracting.  I will be treating answers which suggestions to use applications to “unlock” the PDF as spam, due to the fact the PDF is not locked but is a PDF form.

Answer (score 1):

The message given by sodapdf.com is correct - the PDF does not have any restrictions,
so need not be unlocked.

The Chrome PDF viewer cannot handle it, but that's probably just a bug with displaying
a PDF with a fillable form.

Other PDF readers don't have any problem with it.
I have tried Adobe Acrobat and Foxit Reader.

I suggest posting a
[bug report on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: "I have tried Adobe Acrobat and Foxit Reader.": So on your computer, these software unsecured the PDF for you? I can open the PDF perfectly, but not unsecure it.

Comment: What do you mean by "unsecure"? It's perfectly usable for filling the form.

Comment: I know. I meant to add my own text and pictures.

Comment: This file contains a PDF form, which is a special kind of PDF that requires a special program to create and edit. See [Adobe Pro demo](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/create-fillable-pdf-forms-creator.html). There are other tools - a quick search found [Top 10 Free PDF Form Creator](https://pdf.iskysoft.com/pdf-form/free-pdf-form-creator.html), but there are others, some available as online tools.

Comment: As regarding the password, use [iLovePDF](https://www.ilovepdf.com/unlock_pdf) to remove it, but you will still need a special editor for modifying. It might be simpler to create it from scratch using any of the above tools, and also more legal regarding copyright.

Comment: "As regarding the password": Just to clarify that the original PDF has no passwords?

Comment: It has a password on modifications, but is free to use.

Comment: (1) I tried iLovePDF, but I can't edit the resultant PDF? (2) How would it be easier to recreate it from scratch?

Comment: You cannot edit it except with the right tool. A PDF form is a special format. Use one of the free tools to create a new form, or get [Adobe PDF form creator](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/create-fillable-pdf-forms-creator.html) (free trial available).